# How do I display the current "session" name or "sockname" of a screen session in the status bar?

Tags: gnu-screen, session, status

I run multiple screen sessions each created with 'screen -S ***name***' and I would like to be able to display in the status bar the ***name*** I used to create the current screen session.

However,  I cannot seem to accomplish this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is coming in the next version: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?23738

Also, you can use the terminal variable `$STY`, though people seem to get inconsistent results with it.

Answer (score 2):

Max Cantor refers to a next version in [his answer](https://superuser.com/a/183307/260809). Now it easily works with `%S` in the hardstatus line.

MWE (.screenrc):

```
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%S"
```

This displays the session name *without* the ID (like `${STY#*.}`).

(Same answer to other questions [here](https://superuser.com/a/954751/260809) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31921034/3596168) for completeness).

Answer (score 0):

This was successfully emulated by [how to include screen's session name in hardstatus?](https://superuser.com/questions/212392/how-to-include-screens-session-name-in-hardstatus/212520)

I enhanced it even further, as follows:

```
# generates equivalent of $STY followed by "on $HOST" if $STY is non-standard
backtick 10 60 60 sh -c 'sty=$(screen -ls | grep --color=no -o "$PPID[^[:space:]]*") ; if [ ${sty##*.} = $HOST ] ; then echo $sty ; else echo "$sty on $HOST" ; fi'
# includes session name thanks to backtick 10
hardstatus string "[screen %n%?: %t%? (%10`)] %h"
```