# how to include screen's session name in hardstatus?

Tags: gnu-screen

I use different screen sessions for different projects. Starting screen like `screen -S project1`. Now, I'd like to mention 'project1' in hardstatus line.

Session name can be obtained from environment variable STY: `STY=13539.project1`.
But how to get this into screen? I've tried backtick command and %` in hardstatus, but I can't seem to get it right.

What I did:

.screenrc:

```
hardstatus string '%H:%`'
backtick 0 30 30 echo $STY
```

no luck, empty %`.

```
backtick 0 30 30 sessionname
```

still no luck, sessionname: Not found

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can include this string (with additional information, if desired) in your `$PS1`:

```
\[\e]0;$STY\007
```

inside single quotes in order to delay evaluation of the variable. Then add this to your `~/.screenrc`:

```
hardstatus string '%H:%h'
```

Unfortunately, `screen` doesn't set `$STY` in the environment of the commands it spawns for the `backtick` feature.

Another option, instead of the one above:

```
hardstatus string '%H:%`'
backtick 0 30 30 sh -c 'screen -ls | grep --color=no -o "$PPID[^[:space:]]*"'
```

The advantage of this one is that it follows changes made by using the `sessionname` command. The first option doesn't.

**Edit:**

From [here](http://old.nabble.com/Re:-Session-name-in-status-line-p22456825.html):

> Since $STY is not set yet when screen sources .screenrc, you can use 
>   this trick in your .screenrc:

```
    screen 
    screen $SHELL -c 'screen -X caption always "$STY"'
```

> I.e. send a screen command to the first window.

Comment: For the solution that starts with `backtick`: (1.) is `backtick` a bash builtin? a gnu-screen command? a binary executable? is there a man page? (2.) I know it works because I tried it but how do you get a two line command to execute when it seems like the gnu-screen `.screenrc` syntax requires one line for the `hardstatus` command? (3.) how would I modify your command to allow appending some text after the session name?

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith: `backtick` is a `screen` command. Search for it in the man page for `screen`. It might be best if you post a new question regarding the rest of what you're asking. I don't think hardstatus output can occupy two lines on-screen. You could use `sed` or `awk` instead of `grep` to do what `grep` is doing in my example and also append some extra text.

Comment: When I said "two line" let me restate what I meant, I don't want a two line display for hardstatus. I was confused by the ``%` `` and the `backtick` being on separate lines... they didn't look related but now that I [read the documentation for `backtick`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Backtick.html) I see that the two are related/necessary/valid-syntax (albeit rather strange syntax IMO).

Answer (score 7):

For me this easily works with inserting `%S` in the hardstatus.

MWE (.screenrc):

```
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%S"
```

However, this displays the session name *without* the ID (like `${STY#*.}`); in your example: `project1`.

(Same answer to other questions [here](https://superuser.com/a/954755/260809) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31921034/3596168) for completeness).

Comment: FYI, The "%S" does work on newer versions of gnu-screen (works on Fedora 21 version for me) but not older versions (does not work on CentOS 6 version for me).