# gnu-screen's caption/hardstatus: how do you append text after the session-name?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

For older versions of gnu-screen (i.e. without the `%S`), I found out [how to print the session-name in the hardstatus or caption of gnu-screen by reading this answer](https://superuser.com/a/212520/28756).

The solution is to add the following lines to your `.screenrc`:

```
hardstatus string '%H:%`'
backtick 0 30 30 sh -c 'screen -ls | grep --color=no -o "$PPID[^[:space:]]*"'
```

**How do you append text after the session-name prints?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a question of what are the semantics of the `` %` `` and `backtick` command in gnu-screen. Here's what I found to work:

```
caption always 'gnu-screen: host=%H, session=%`, text message to append'
backtick 0 30 30 bash -c 'screen -ls | grep --color=no -o "$PPID[^[:space:]]*"'
```

You need to [read the documentation on gnu-screen `backtick`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Backtick.html) to be able to understand what is happening. Once you read that the solution is much more straight forward.